# qnetworkreply no statuscode or error but failing

Tags: c++, qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkreply, qnetworkrequest

Im trying to find out what goes wrong when doing a get request in qt.
I have the following slots attached to my `networkmanager`:

```cpp
connect(mgr,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(requestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));

    connect(mgr, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)),
            this, SLOT(slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)));
```

The request finished is like:

```cpp
    void FirebaseInteractor::requestFinished(QNetworkReply *rep)
    {
        QVariant statusCode = rep->attribute( QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute );
        int status = statusCode.toInt();
        if ( status != 200 )
        {
            QString reason = rep->attribute( QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute ).toString();
            qDebug() << "Pushnotification Request failed : " <<reason;
        }
        else{
            qDebug() << "Pushnotification has been send: ";
        }
        if ( !statusCode.isValid() )
        {

            QString status = statusCode.toString(); // or status_code.toInt();
            qDebug() << "Failing " << status;
            int code = statusCode.toInt();
            qDebug() << "Pushnotification Request failed invalid status code." << QString::number(code);
            QString reason = rep->attribute( QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute ).toString();
            qDebug() << "reason " << reason;
            return;
        }
    }
```

However Status is always empty `Failing` and `reason` is printed but there is no value after it (i was expecting a reason e.g. timeout, 401 etc).

I also tried:

```cpp
    int status = statusCode.toInt();

    if ( status != 200 )
    {
        QString reason = rep->attribute( QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute ).toString();
        qDebug() << "Pushnotification Request failed : " <<reason;
    }
    else{
        qDebug() << "Pushnotification has been send: ";
    }

But all reasons/codes are empty.

I also added:

    void FirebaseInteractor::slotError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError error)
    {
        qDebug() << "slotError" << error;
    }
```

but this is not called.

How can I find out whats going wrong?

Comment: what is it that you are trying to accomplish? if you want to check success, just switch on `reply->error()`

Comment: @waqar I want to see the reason why a request is failing (e.g server returns 401, thereis a timeout etc). currently i can not see any reason or statuscode why the build is failing.

Comment: `if ( !statusCode.isValid() )` means `statusCode` is of `QMetaType::UnknownType`, and if that happens, there isn't going to be any information about the `status code`. It should be valid even if the request failed.

Comment: @Waqar how can I find out why it is failing? it is working on one pc not on the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the error directly using:

```
qDebug() << reply->error();
```

This won't work if the network request never happened:

```
    if ( !statusCode.isValid() )
```

Because this means that the `QVariant` itself is invalid and has type `QMetaType::UnknownType` [Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#isValid). Hence it will not give any information about what went wrong in the http request. To fix this, here's a simple example:

```
if (statusCode.isValid()) { // it needs to be valid
    qDebug() << "Status Code: " << statusCode.toString();
}
```

Alternatively, you can switch on [`QNetworkReply::Error()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkreply.html#error)

```cpp
void FirebaseInteractor::requestFinished(QNetworkReply *rep)
{
    switch (rep->error())
    {
       case QNetworkReply::NoError:
       // No error
       return;
       case QNetworkReply::TimeoutError:
       {
           auto httpStatus =
               reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
           auto httpStatusMessage = reply->attribute(
        QNetworkRequest::HttpReasonPhraseAttribute).toByteArray();
        //...
        break;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: if isValid is false how will it run  qDebug() << "Status Code: " << statusCode.toString();. I have no clue what the error is do I need to make a case for every possible value from rep->error?

Comment: qDebug() << rep->error(); is giving me the error, SslHandshakeFailedError

Comment: if `isValid` is false, that could mean anything, for e.g, the network mgr wasn't able to make the request, or anything. I am not sure about that.

Comment: you pointed me in the right direction 'qDebug() << rep->error(); ' solved it, if you update it in your answer i will accept

Comment: `SslHandshakeFailedError` occurs when ssl certificates are not found. Make sure you have openssl installed and available. Also you can explicitly read certificates using: `QSslCertificate::fromPath()` and set your `QSslConfiguration`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QByteArray data;
QUrl urlObject(url);
auto reply = manager->post(req,data);
QEventLoop eventLoop;
connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished,&eventLoop,&QEventLoop::quit);
eventLoop.exec();
qDebug()<<"reply->error()::::::::"<<reply->error();
```